# Ruby procs and calling methods without instantiation

Tags: ruby, object, rspec, proc

I'm trying to get this RSpec test pasted below to pass, but I'm lost on how I should call `multiply_by`. I believe that I have to store `multiply_by` as a proc so that it can be called on the `expect` line, but how do I get access to the `multiply_by` method if I don't instantiate the `NumProcessor` class? Maybe I'm not supposed to make `NumProcessor` a class, but I need to use `.` operator so I can do `NumProcessor.multiply_by`, so I'm unclear on that. There is something I'm missing about how procs work in ruby, I believe. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
# First attempt 
class NumProcessor
  def multiply_by(num)
    multiply_by = Proc.new { |num| num * 2} 
  end
end

# Trying to write code to make this test pass without changing it
describe 'NumProcessor#multiply_by' do
  it 'should double' do
    double = NumProcessor.multiply_by(2)
    expect(double.call(4)).to eq(8)
  end
end
```

**Updated Tests**

```
class NumProcessor
  def self.multiply_by(factor)
    Proc.new { |num| num * factor} 
  end
end

# Trying to write code to make this test pass without changing it
describe 'NumProcessor#multiply_by' do
  it 'should double' do
    double = NumProcessor.multiply_by(2)
    expect(double.call(2)).to eq(4)
  end
  it 'should triple' do
    triple = NumProcessor.multiply_by(3)
    expect(triple.call(2)).to eq(6)
  end
end
```

Got them working!

Comment: `number` is unused, btw.

Comment: Sorry about that, guys; that was a typo.

Comment: now the outer `num` is unused.

Comment: @cloud_user_2016 apart from typos, it's usually better to leave code unchanged. Otherwise question and answer(s) might diverge over time.

Comment: @Stefan that makes sense. My bad this is my first time posting on StackOverflow. Should I remove the updated tests that I added later?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev do you mean num is unused on the original test? If so, yeah, you're completely right. I didn't understand how procs worked. What I didn't realize is that whatever you pass to `.call` is passed to the block of the proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to use `.` operator so I can do `NumProcessor.multiply_by`

In order to call the method on the class itself, you have to define a so-called *class method*, e.g. by prefixing it with `self.`: (see [Methods – Scope](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Scope))

```
class NumProcessor
  def self.multiply_by(number)
    # ...
  end
end
```

You can now call it via:

```
NumProcessor.multiply_by(4)
#=> #<Proc:...>
```

If you are not going to create instances of `NumProcessor`, you can make it a [module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html):

```
module NumProcessor
  def self.multiply_by(number)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Last not least there's [`module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#module_function-method) – it turns a public *instance method* (one without `self.`) into both, a class method and a private instance method:

```
module NumProcessor
  def multiply_by(number)
    # ...
  end
  module_function :multiply_by
end
```

This is how the built-in [`Math`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Math.html) module is implemented. The method can be called as a class method:

```
NumProcessor.multiply_by(4)
#=> #<Proc:...>
```

But you can also include the module into another class in order to call its methods without explicit receiver:

```
class Foo
  include NumProcessor

  def bar
    multiply_by(4)
  end
end
```

while not exposing it to the outside:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar
#=> #<Proc:...>

foo.multiply_by(4)
# NoMethodError: private method `multiply_by' called
```

---

Regarding your implementation:

- the `multiply_by =` assignment is superfluous, because the `multiply_by` variable isn't used afterwards
- the `number` argument isn't used
- despite its name, `multiply_by(number)` always multiplies by 2 (instead of multiplying by `number`)

To fix it, I'd implement it as: (see the docs for [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Proc.html) which uses the very same implementation as an example)

```
def multiply_by(factor)
  Proc.new { |n| n * factor }
end
```

A corresponding test could look like this:

```
describe 'NumProcessor' do
  describe '.multiply_by' do
    let(:multplier) { NumProcessor.multiply_by(factor) }

    context 'with a factor of 2' do
      let(:factor) { 2 }

      it 'should double' do
        expect(multiplier.call(4)).to eq(8)
      end
    end

    context 'with a factor of 3' do
      let(:factor) { 3 }

      it 'should triple' do
        expect(multiplier.call(4)).to eq(12)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. This was an excellent explanation. The key thing I was missing was when `multiplier.call(2)` is executed, the argument `2` in this instance is passed to the block within the proc.

Answer (score 0):

Change `multiply_by` to a class method by adding `self.` in the start of the method name.

```rb
class NumProcessor
  def self.multiply_by(number)
    multiply_by = Proc.new { |num| num * 2} 
  end
end
```

This will allow a call like `NumProcessor.multiply_by(4)`